# Arkham Asylum : Final Boss - Quickly Beating Joker's Henchman

Tags: batman-arkham-asylum

After rebuying the game to finally get to play it (it was cheaper to buy a PS3 version than to buy the controller needed to get the PC version to play like I want), I have stormed the game and really enjoyed it.

Except for the final boss. In my opinion it has ruined the game for me. It is so stressful. Sure Poison Ivy's fight was as well but it was more difficult than stressful. The time allocated to dispose of the henchman until Joker turns his back so I can pull him off the platform is just too short for me. Perhaps this is just me. Did anyone else have this annoyance with the final boss?

I have tried various strategies including IGN's method and it just doesn't work. I even tried using Explosive Gel as well. Did anyone manage to find a fool-proof strategy?

Comment: No strategy is fool-proof. I take time between button presses, waiting until batman finishes his last move before pressing again and frequently dodge after a punch. This gives lots of critical combos which will immediately knock enemies down (or into an electrified fence) while keeping the combo and leaves you time to react. If you try to target enemies that are isolated, it will keep you safer. For the Joker fight, knock enemies into the electric fence for quick kills. Dodge is your friend. I recommend MotioninJoy to use your dualshock3 controller on PC so you needn't buy a new controller.

Comment: Note that you can use your combat batclaw to pull him off without having to aim. Watching a video may help you: [This one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aczi-kD3Eso&t=3m40s) makes no use of the combo system and does just fine.

Comment: @Jeremy What difficulty are you playing the game on?

Answer (score 4):

I always liked standing with my back to the walls, batclawing a few henchmen my way and then jumping over them, pushing them into an electric demise.

Rinse, repeat.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say what you're doing wrong without a video of you gameplay, but I'd say the issue is probably that your not clawing the henchmen on the balcony. Make sure to do that whenever you see them. Also, try to claw some of the henchmen to you before one of the titans charges at you.